# Photoshop script: Access the main window object of the active document

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I want to programmatically change the viewer position and scroll. There has to be a main window object or something, but I can't figure out how to access it. Just to be clear, I don't want to create a new window. All I want to do is something like

```
Window.location = [0,0,]
```

to move the viewer to that position (ie. scroll to that position)

Comment: bueller... bueller...